# Suggest amend tag [port-fowarding] to [port-forwarding]

Tags: support

Suggest amend tag [port-fowarding] to [port-forwarding]. Looks like a spelling error to me.

Comment: Wow, nice catch, can't believe I haven't noticed that!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks much for noticing this and pointing it out here.  The issue has been corrected!

Comment: No worries - and wow, that was quick! ;)

Comment: Like a bunny ;)